# Mongo staled with too much insertions

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I trying to use mongodb to run a multiagent simulation.

I have one mongo instance in the same server that runs the simulation program, but when I have too much agents (~100.000 in 10 simulation steps) the mongodb becomes stalled during seconds.

The code for insert data in mongo is similar to:

```
if( mongo_client( &m_conn , m_dbhost.c_str(), m_dbport ) != MONGO_OK ) {
    cout << "failed to connect '" << m_dbhost << ":" << m_dbport << "'\n";
    cout << "  mongo error: " << m_conn.err << endl;
    return;
}
bson_init( &b );
bson_append_new_oid( &b, "_id" ) != BSON_OK );
bson_append_double( &b, "time", time );
bson_append_double( &b, "x", posx );
bson_append_double( &b, "y", posy );
bson_finish( &b );

if( mongo_insert( &m_conn , ns.c_str() , &b, NULL ) != MONGO_OK ){
    cout << "failed to insert in mongo\n";
}
bson_destroy( &b );
mongo_disconnect( &m_conn );
```

Also, during the simulation, If I try to access using the mongo-shell, I also get errors:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.1
connecting to: test
Wed Apr  3 10:10:24.870 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
exception: connect failed
```

After the simulation is ended, the mongo shell gets responsive again, and I can check that there is data in the database but it is discontinued. In the example, the agent m0n999 saved only 6 of 10 steps:

```
> show dbs
dB0B7F527F0FA45518712C8CB27611BD7   5.951171875GB
local   0.078125GB
> db.ins.m0n999.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515bdf564c60ec1e000003e7"), "time" : 1, "x" : 1.1, "y" : 8.1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515be0214c60ec1e0001075f"), "time" : 2, "x" : 1.2000000000000002, "y" : 8.2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515be1c04c60ec1e0002da3a"), "time" : 4, "x" : 1.4000000000000004, "y" : 8.399999999999999 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515be2934c60ec1e0003b82c"), "time" : 5, "x" : 1.5000000000000004, "y" : 8.499999999999998 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515be3664c60ec1e000497cf"), "time" : 6, "x" : 1.6000000000000005, "y" : 8.599999999999998 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515be6cc4c60ec1e000824b2"), "time" : 10, "x" : 2.000000000000001, "y" : 8.999999999999996 }
>
```

How can solve this problem? How can avoid the lost of connections and recover from mongo stalls?

**UPDATE**
I'm getting in the *global* log errors like:

```
    "Wed Apr  3 11:53:00.379 [conn1378573] error: hashtable namespace index max chain reached:1335",
    "Wed Apr  3 11:53:00.379 [conn1378573] error: hashtable namespace index max chain reached:1335",
    "Wed Apr  3 11:53:00.379 [conn1378573] error: hashtable namespace index max chain reached:1335",
    "Wed Apr  3 11:53:00.379 [conn1378573] error: hashtable namespace index max chain reached:1335",
    "Wed Apr  3 11:53:00.379 [conn1378573] end connection 127.0.0.1:40748 (1 connection now open)",
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the log?

Comment: @assylias, great, I added a log output fragment with errors

Comment: How many collections does your test create? You can view this by running either "show collections" or "db.getCollectionNames()" against your database in the mongo shell.

Comment: @JamesWahlin I create a collection per agent roughly 100000

Comment: This sounds like you may be hitting a limit on the # of namespaces. See the the following from the mongodb docs for details: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#namespaces

Comment: I fixed the use of too much namespaces, now I'm using 4~10 only. But also I getting failed to connect 'localhost:27017'  mongo error: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, it has two errors:

- I was creating too much collections. I changed from one collection per Agent, to only on collection per simulation proccess.
- I was creating too much connections. I changed from one connection per Agent iteration, to only one connection per simulation step.